# PHPDoc references a dotenv entry

Tags: php, phpdoc, phpdotenv

How should i reference on a PHPdoc block that if the variable is not present it will check a dotenv setting for it?

```
 /**
 * Class constructor.
 *
 *  Created Class Object.
 *
 * @param null $url     - access url for api
 */

public function __construct($url = null)
{
     if (! isset($url)) {
        $url = env('CLASS_URL', null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds very case specific. I'd just note it down after the `access url for api` part

Comment: It tries specific parameter and if not present checks .env. I understand it is not a language feature but it is far from specific

Comment: I don't think there's specific PHPDoc syntax to indicate what it does if the parameter is not provided other than saying what the default value is.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably that `env()` function is one you have defined. As such, I'd use the `@see env()` tag to highlight that it is used to find a value when it's not given via argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can split it by making a static `createFromEnv()` with a formless description which creates the instance. This way it's more obvious from where `$url` is taken.

Disadvantage is that the creator must make the decision explicitly whether to call `createFromEnv` or `__construct`.